# Retrieving data from S3 is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my application i use `S3` to store user data. User has files and each file has its id and i need to store for each file its data and a snapshot image (png). I store the data in the following architecture:

```
Main files bucket >
       File_id_folder >
          file.data
          file.png
       File_id_folder >
          file.data
          file.png
       File_id_folder >
          file.data
          file.png
```

My problem is that retrieving the files from S3 takes a lot of time. It can take about a minute  to get 5 png files.

The size of my png files is around 100K. I use the the `N.California` region and download the files from `Israel`. The png files are being downloaded through iOS application (used to initialize UIImage)

What can i do to improve S3 performance?

Comment: Erik, to get more relevant answers, I strongly advise you to add *a lot* more information on what you are doing. Simply saying that *"I have objects in S3 and it's slow to download them"* isn't enough. For instance, what are the sizes of your files? What S3 region are you using? Where are the files being downloaded? How are you downloading them (through your web browser? with code? show the code)? And so on...

Comment: I added more info to my original question

Comment: You now mention iOS applications and Israel<-->N.California. Have you measured the latency and packet loss between the end users experiencing slowness and your S3 bucket? That could probably explain slowness. And if that's the case, your best bet to improve performance would be to either shrink your images *a lot*, or to use a CDN such as CloudFront to serve your content (latency would likely improve, but if you are talking about mobile network, then that might be the biggest part of the latency, that you can't really do anything to improve...).

Comment: Unless you are doing *many hundreds of requests per second for the same set of images*, then S3 is probably the last place you should investigate.

Comment: I am not doing hundreds of requests per second but i am sure that the problem is with the access to S3

Comment: @Erik, That's too quick conclusion. There are 2 EU regions and 3 Asia Regions close to Israel. Could you have a try to copy the same contents to one of these regions, how is the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep your images in s3, and need to download them as fast as possible from far-flung places (like Israel), consider using a AWS cloudfront distribution on your s3 bucket so that images can be served from the data center closest to where you are downloading them.

Adding cloudfront will be simple to do, and cost next to nothing to at least test and see if it helps.

If after adding cloudfront, and it is still slower than you think it should be, I would look into the other aspects of your solution. It may be slow because of other factors unrelated to AWS.